# WebService PHP MySQL hacer dos consultas

Tags: php, mysqli, webservice, mysqldb

Tengo este WebService en php y MySQL y la intención es que haga la $consulta2 (que es un update) y despúes ejecute la $consulta que es un SELECT.

Según veo en phpMyAdmin está ejecutando el UPDATE, pero el cliente no está recibiendo el SELECT. He comprobado las consultas en phpMyAmdin así que no pondré la sentencia SQL pues son correctas, a no ser que lo pidáis.

Código PHP:

```
$consulta1 = $_POST["consulta"];
$consulta2 = $_POST["consulta2"];

$resultado2 = mysqli_query($mysqli,$consulta2);
        if ($resultado2) 
        {
            mysqli_free_result($resultado2);
            $resultado= mysqli_query($mysqli,$consulta);
            $arraySalida = array();
            while($registro = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($resultado) ):
                $cadena = "{$registro['nom']};{$registro['per']};{$registro['lug']};{$registro['est']};{$registro['hEnt']};{$registro['hR']};{$registro['hE']};{$registro['hC']};{$registro['obs']};{$registro['pri']};{$registro['idI']};{$registro['ref']};{$registro['fra']};{$registro['eq']};{$registro['dificultad']}";
                 $arraySalida[]= $cadena;
            endwhile;

            echo implode("<",$arraySalida);  

            mysqli_free_result($resultado);
        }
```

El problema que yo he dectectado es que una vez que hace un mysqli_query ya no hace el otro, he probado a hacer el mysqli_query del UPDATE antes del echo implode() y me actualiza la base de datos pero no me envía el select del echo implode(). Y si solo hago el SELECT recibo en el cliente los datos

Comment: Que librería estas utilizando para los web services? A mi en particular me funcionó muy bien NuSOAP (https://sourceforge.net/projects/nusoap/). Puede que el error esté al devolver los datos en el servicio web más que en la consulta. Te recomiendo verificar la seguridad de tu aplicación ya que ejecutar consultas recibidas por el POST puede ser un poco peligroso, algo que también te recomendaría es utilizar el objeto PDO para las consultas, es mas seguro y prolijo (http://php.net/manual/es/book.pdo.php) Espero haber ayudado en algo, saludos!

Comment: Estoy usando PHP puro, sin librerias. Ya que que con $POST hay reisgo de SQL inyection y demaás, gracias por el aviso. Es un problema de que hace una consulta u otra, no las dos. Una vez que hace el mysqli_query ya no saca nada más.

Comment: el error debe estar en _mysqli_free_result($resultado2);_ probaste comentando esta linea?

Comment: @ blov80 efectivamente por ahi debería estar el error, si te fijas en la solución que he dado esa linea ya no esta ahí

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta solución me funciona:

```
$consulta1 = $_POST["consulta"];
$consulta2 = $_POST["consulta2"];
//$consulta = "SELECT nom,per,lug,est,hEnt,hR,hE,hC,obs,pri,idI,ref,fra,eq,dificultad,ordenEv FROM EvaPruThyssen WHERE lug ='EXPO TEMPORAL SALA 1' ORDER BY ordenEv ";
$resultado= mysqli_query($mysqli,$consulta1);
        $arraySalida = array();
        while($registro = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($resultado) ):
     $cadena = "{$registro['nom']};{$registro['per']};{$registro['lug']};{$registro['est']};{$registro['hEnt']};{$registro['hR']};{$registro['hE']};{$registro['hC']};{$registro['obs']};{$registro['pri']};{$registro['idI']};{$registro['ref']};{$registro['fra']};{$registro['eq']};{$registro['dificultad']}";
                 $arraySalida[]= $cadena;
        endwhile;
        //echo $consulta;

        echo implode("<",$arraySalida);  


        mysqli_free_result($resultado);
$resultado = mysqli_query($mysqli,$consulta2);
if ($resultado) 
{
     $correcto ="1";
     //echo $consulta;
} 
mysqli_free_result($resultado);
```